# Many to Many Post to Tag Query

Tags: sql

I have a many to many relationships between posts and tags

## Post

- id
- title

## Tag

- id
- title

## TagToPost

- A | tag
- B | post

Looking to perform a search for posts with a certain combination of tags.

```
SELECT * FROM "Post"
JOIN "TagToPost" "tag" ON "tag"."B" = "Post".id
JOIN "Tag" ON "tag"."A" = "Tag"."id"
WHERE ("Tag"."id" = '1') AND 
(
    ("Tag"."id" = '2') OR 
    ("Tag"."id" = '3')
)
```

Getting an empty result. Could someone guide me on how this query should work?

Comment: Tag.id can never be 1, and also 2 or 3 at the same time.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve])

Comment: @SergioPellegrini . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have to join all the three tables. Since you only want the Post information.

```
SELECT * FROM "Post" where id in (
select postid from TagToPost Tag WHERE ("Tag"."id" = '1') AND 
(("Tag"."id" = '2') OR ("Tag"."id" = '3')))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want posts with tag "1" and "2" or "3".  If so, use aggregation:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Post p JOIN
     TagToPost tp
     ON tp.post_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t.id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.id IN (2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

Note:  There are shortcuts in some databases for the `HAVING`.  For instance, in MySQL:

```
HAVING SUM( t.id = 1 ) > 0 AND
       SUM( t.id IN (2, 3)  ) > 0
```

But these depend on the database.